# Print line numbers from grep separated with a comma

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut

I used grep to get the line numbers from a file where a particular string occurred. What if I want these line numbers to appear in on line separated by a comma not vertically in a line?

```
cFont=$(grep -icE "<font *" $htmlFile)
if [ $cFont -gt 0 ] ; then
  echo "There are $cFont line(s) with <font> tag, they are: " >> ~/Desktop/errors.txt
  grep -inE "<font *" $htmlFile |cut -f1 -d: >> ~/Desktop/errors.txt
fi
```

The out put was

```
There are 4 line(s) with <font> tag, they are: 
14
43
46
72
```

I want it to be

```
There are 4 line(s) with <font> tag, they are: 
14, 43, 46, 72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cut -f1 -d:` you can use awk:

```bash
awk 'NR > 1 {printf "%s, ", p} {p=$0} END {print p}' file

14, 43, 46, 72
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
grep -inE "<font *" $htmlFile |cut -f1 -d:| tr '\n' ','|sed -e "s/,$//" >> ~/Desktop/errors.tr
```